# Express not sending response once bulk insert is complete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Implementing bulk insert in `mongodb` using mongoose.
The data is successfully getting saved in DB but the express is not sending the response back.

Tried it using `insertMany` also tried `bulkWrite`

```
try {
  await Collection.insertMany(docsToBeInserted);
  console.log("Insert Successful");
  res.status(200).send('ok'); 
} catch(err) {
  res.status(500).json({err})
}
```

Insert Successful is getting print and all the documents are successfully inserted in database but in client the call never completes after some time the call fails throwing `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of insertMany into a variable, and send it as response like this:

```
try {
  const response = await Collection.insertMany(docsToBeInserted);
  console.log("Insert Successful");
  return res.status(200).send(response.data);
} catch (err) {
  return res.status(500).json({ err })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this specific case in this way:

```
return Collection.insertMany(docsToBeInserted)
.then(res => {
     res.status(200).send('ok');
})
.catch(err => {
     res.status(500).json({ err })
});
```

I have removed `async-await` and leveraged `Promise` returned by `insertMany` into sending the apt response according to your sample code.

You can also replace `res.status(200).send('ok')` with `res.send('ok')` as Express will set Http status to 200.

I would recommend adding `console.error(err)` statement to your error handling on the code for the stack trace.

Comment: There is no error it doesn't get into the catch block, it's just not sending any response to the client. It's totally weird and async-await is just syntactical sugar over 
promises so that will not make any difference any way I tried with the older syntax of then-catch but still same problem

Comment: Suddenly without any change everything starts working with the same code, Do you have any idea, as if express has some default timeout after which it doesn't send any response?